# Can anyone tell me why my mail is being classified as spam (headers included)

Tags: php, email, email-spam

Here is the situation.

I have both an SMTP server which accepts only authentication.

I also have a VPS with no SMTP server, so the PHP on that VPS sends emails using PEAR to the SMTP server for sending.

For some reason emails are getting classified as Spam always. 
Can someone take a look at the following headers and give me a pointer to why this might be happening?

Some stuff has been *****'d out for security.

I'm new to VPS stuff so I guess I might have some dodgy config somewhere, so I need some advice on this one.

Thanks guys!

```
Microsoft Mail Internet Headers Version 2.0
    Received: from moutng.k*****.de ([212.227.17.8]) by ***** with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
         Sat, 12 Feb 2011 11:30:09 +0000
    Received: from localhost (*****.onlinehome-server.info [*****])
        by mrelayeu.k*****.de (node=mreu1) with ESMTP (Nemesis)
        id 0Lm8JB-1QNpTc29Yn-00a9O2; Sat, 12 Feb 2011 12:30:09 +0100
    From: Logeek <log@*****.com>
    To: A King <aking@*****.co.uk>
    Subject: Hi!
    Message-Id: <0Lm8JB-1QNpTc29Yn-00a9O2@mrelayeu.k*****.de>
    Date: Sat, 12 Feb 2011 12:30:09 +0100
    X-Provags-ID: *****
    Return-Path: log@*****.com
    X-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Feb 2011 11:30:09.0931 (UTC) FILETIME=[34CC45B0:01CBCAA8]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I'm not really good at email headers but if an Email is sent from and address in which the domain is not equal to the domain the email was sent from for example: a message sent by **admin@thispage.com** from the server **otherpage.com** will get marked as spam: When using a SMTP server **smtp.thispage.com** as a local user on that server for example **admin@thispage.com** the message will be sent from this server and the email wil not be marked as spam. But when sending it as user **admin@thispage.com** from a different domain using PEAR the message will normally be marked as spam.

Comment: This email was revived from `moutng.k*****.de` but the senders domain is `*****.com`. They do not match.

Comment: k*****.de is the SMTP server, *****.com is an account on that SMTP server.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, the account domain and the server domain don't match.

Comment: So the only way to fix this would be to send email from the webserver, perhaps installing its own SMTP server?

Comment: Yes that or writing a script in PHP or PEAR or any other server-side language for sending emails. Just make sure that you protect it using a secret key or something similar. Maybe even with a session/cookies and requiring to login.

Comment: Metod, I am going to try to change my hostname in order to sort this out, and I am moving my problem over to serverfault. Thanks for the advice.